# Variables/parameters in Sqlite query for Iphone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

In my Iphone App I have created this query:

```
"SELECT * FROM visuel where id_visuel = 1"
```

And so I have this function that works very well:

```
- (void)getVisuel {

    visuelArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    sqlite3 *database;

    if(sqlite3_open([self.databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_reset(getVisuelStatement);

        while(sqlite3_step(getVisuelParcStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            NSString *aTitle = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(getVisuelStatement , 2)];
            NSString *aLpath = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(getVisuelStatement , 3)];

            Visuel *aVisuel = [[Visuel alloc] initWithName:aTitle lpath:aLpath];

            [visuelArray addObject:aVisuel];
        }
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);

}
```

What I want is to change the query like this: "SELECT * FROM visuel where id_visuel = ?" 
I don't want to have a static id, but I don't know how to do that.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first change your query to your parameterized query like you have there.  Then, just before you call `sqlite3_step` bind the right id to the parameter:

```
sqlite3_reset(getVisuelStatement);

//Add these two lines
int visuelId = 1;  //Put whatever id you want in here.
sqlite3_bind_int(getVisuelParcStatement, 1, visuelId);

while(sqlite3_step(getVisuelParcStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
```

Comment: Thanks that help. But now, If I do what you say I will have to right: for visuelId =1 do that... visualId =2 do that............ 
I have created a UITableView and I want for example to put the number of the line for the visuelId. Hos to do that?