# How to sanitize database inputs in C or Objective-C?

Tags: sql, objective-c, c, sqlite, sql-injection

I am creating an iPhone app (if that matters) in Objective-C, and I use SQLite storage. I want to sanitize the database inputs to prevent the user from doing something like

```
Robert'); DROP TABLE Students; --
```

What is the best way to do this in C or Objective-C?

---

I tried replacing `'` with `''` but I am sure this is not enough.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variables/parameters in Sqlite query for Iphone App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878425/variables-parameters-in-sqlite-query-for-iphone-app)

Comment: @Forgotten Semicolon that is only for integers, not for strings.

Comment: Where have I seen that? !? ... [Ah! xkcd, of course](http://xkcd.com/327/) (2007-10-10) ... is little bobby tables still studying?

Comment: @pmg yeah his record was dropped again, so he had to do some years over.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best thing to do is to never, ever, under any circumstances, even in those special cases where you just *know* it would be easier but really seriously I mean this DO NOT construct SQL statements by concatenating the parameters values into the statement.  Use parameter markers and bind the values to the markers.  This is **the way** to avoid SQL injection attacks.  Everything else is just so much wasted time and effort because for every N things you think to alter/modify/check for in the parameters typed in by your user somebody is going to think of thing N+1.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: So you mean something like `FGMakeSQL(@"SELECT Name FROM Notes WHERE Id=?", noteId)`? What are the things I actually need to escape? Just `'`s or also other characters?

Comment: @Radek: I don't think you'd need to escape anything.