# Pass userName and organization code from sqlite query in iphone

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite

How to pass userName and organizationCode from query in sqlite iPhone I want that it should fetch data from table where organization code and userName should be

Like the below any idea how to pass I have given what I want in general sense.

```
    const char *sql = "select * from library where userName='appDelegate.userName' organizationCode='appDelegate.organizationCode'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use parameters like this:

```
const char *sql = "select * from library where userName=? organizationCode=?";
```

and bind them with statements like this:

```
sqlite3_bind_text(sql , 1, [appDelegate.userName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(sql , 2, [appDelegate.organizationCode], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878425/variables-parameters-in-sqlite-query-for-iphone-app) of how to make this kind of call.